# How to send the SMS using blackberry application

Tags: blackberry, sms

How to send the SMS using blackberry application?

Comment: Here you go [Send SMS using java](http://www.ehow.com/how_5318837_send-sms-using-java.html)

Answer (score 2):

you should check sms RIM API for that

http://myhowto.org/java/j2me/22-sending-and-receiving-gsm-sms-on-blackberry-using-rim-apis/

Answer (score -1):

```
 Detect the phone's network programmatically to send sms
public int getNetworkType() {
        int type = 0;
        int networkType = RadioInfo.getNetworkType();
        switch (networkType) {
        case RadioInfo.NETWORK_GPRS: // GSM
            type = 0;
            break;
        case RadioInfo.NETWORK_CDMA: //CDMA
            type = 1;
            break;
        case RadioInfo.NETWORK_IDEN: //GSM
            type = 0;
            break;
        default:
            type = 0; //GSM
            break;
        }
        return type;
    }
```

Comment: How does this relate to the question?